# WebGL on Chrome for Windows : warning X3206 when cast float to int

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

I think i found a strange bug of Windows version of the Chrome WebGL implementation. Linking a shader with a cast float to int cause an "warning X3206: implicit truncation of vector type" error. I have tried many way to avoid it, but no chance.

for example :

```
int i;
vec3 u = vec3(1.5, 2.5, 3.5);
float z = u.z;

i = int(u.z): // warning X3206: implicit truncation of vector type
i = int(z):  // warning X3206: implicit truncation of vector type
```

The strange thing is that this vertex program perfectly works on the Linux version on the same computer (same graphic card). Is it a driver issue ? (I have tested on two Windows version with two different graphic cards with the same result). Other strange thing (to me) : X3206 is ordinary an DirectX error (?!) what is the relation with WebGL ?

Here is the complete shader  i use and cause the Warning:

```
#define MATRIX_ARRAY_SIZE 48

/* vertex attributes */
attribute vec4 p;
attribute vec3 n;
attribute vec3 u;
attribute vec3 t;
attribute vec3 b;
attribute vec4 c;
attribute vec4 i;
attribute vec4 w;

/* enable vertex weight */
uniform bool ENw;

/* enable comput tangent */
uniform bool ENt;

/* eye view matrix */
uniform mat4 MEV;

/* transform matrices */
uniform mat4 MXF[MATRIX_ARRAY_SIZE];

/* transform normal matrices */
uniform mat3 MNR[MATRIX_ARRAY_SIZE];

/* varying fragment shader */
varying vec4 Vp;
varying vec3 Vn;
varying vec2 Vu;
varying vec3 Vt;
varying vec3 Vb;
varying vec4 Vc;

void main(void) {

    /* Position et Normal transform */
    if(ENw) { /* enable vertex weight */

        Vp = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        Vn = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

        Vp += (MXF[int(i.x)] * p) * w.x;
        Vn += (MNR[int(i.x)] * n) * w.x;

        Vp += (MXF[int(i.y)] * p) * w.y;
        Vn += (MNR[int(i.y)] * n) * w.y;

        Vp += (MXF[int(i.z)] * p) * w.z;
        Vn += (MNR[int(i.z)] * n) * w.z;

        Vp += (MXF[int(i.w)] * p) * w.w;
        Vn += (MNR[int(i.w)] * n) * w.w;

    } else {

        Vp = MXF[0] * p;
        Vn = MNR[0] * n;
    }

    /* Tangent et Binormal transform */
    if(ENt) { /* enable comput tangent */

        vec3 Cz = cross(Vn, vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
        vec3 Cy = cross(Vn, vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));

        if(length(Cz) > length(Cy)) {
            Vt = Cz;
        } else {
            Vt = Cy;
        }

        Vb = cross(Vn, Vt); 

    } else {

        Vt = t;
        Vb = b;
    }

    /* Texcoord et color */
    Vu = u.xy;
    Vc = c;
    gl_PointSize = u.z;
    gl_Position = MEV * Vp;
}
```

If someone found an elegant workaround...

Answer (score 1):

Chrome's and Firefox's WebGL in Windows is implemented with [ANGLE](http://code.google.com/p/angleproject/), which in turn uses DirectX as the underlying API. Then, it doesn't come as a surprise that certain DirectX restrictions/warnings/errors rise when using WebGL there.

And you indeed are truncating a float type, use `T floor(T)` or `T ceil(T)` to obtain more meaningful results and no warnings.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're running out of uniforms.

48 mat3s + 49 mat4s + 2 bools = 1218 values / 4 = at least 306 uniform vectors needed

On my GPU gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS) only returns 254.

Note that 306 uniform vectors is for a perfectly optimizing GLSL compiler. For an un-optimized compiler it might internally use 3 vec4s for mat3 and a full vec4 for each bool making it need more uniform vectors.

That seems to be the case since if I lower MATRIX_ARRAY_SIZE to 35 and it works on my machine and 36 fails.

35 mat3s each using 3 vectors + 36 mat4s each using 4 vectors + 2 bools each using 1 vector = 249 vectors required. One more, 36 requires 257 which is 3 more than my GPU driver supports which is why it fails.

Note 128 is the minimum number of vertex uniform vectors required to be supported which means if you want it to work everywhere you'd need to set MATRIX_ARRAY_SIZE to 17.  On the other hand I don't know what uniforms you're using in your fragment shader. Alternatively you could query the number of uniform vectors supported and modify your shader source at runtime.

Here's a sample that works for me
http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/474Et/2/

Change the 35 at the top back to 48 and it will generate the same error message.

It sucks that the error message is cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in [ANGLE revision 1557](http://code.google.com/p/angleproject/source/detail?r=1557). It will take a while for this fix to become available in mainstream Chrome.